# Sum and Count in nested foreign key relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Building():

class Floor():
    building = models.ForeignKey("Building")

class Suite():
    floor = models.ForeignKey("Floor")
    area = models.FloatField()
    available = models.BooleanField()
```

In the serializer for Building, across the whole building, I would like to

- count 'available' suites
- sum 'available' suites 'area' fields

I'm pretty sure that I can sum area of a list of suites like this:

```
models.Suite.objects.filter(Q(available=True)).aggregate(Sum('area'))
```

I don't know how to nest this so that I can query the data for the entire building...

Comment: what do you mean by: " nest this so that you can query the data for the entire building", you want to nest ```area aggregate``` result in the BuildingSeriaizer ?

Comment: I could do the example query for a single floor, but I can't figure out how to do every suite in the building.

Comment: you mean: ```aggregate all available suite area``` of each building, right ?

Comment: No just a single building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do these:

To count available suites in a building:

```
Suite.objects.filter(floor__building=building, available=True).count()
```

To sum available suites' areas:

```
Suite.objects.filter(floor__building=building, available=True).aggregate(Sum('area'))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there a way to sum available suite areas from the `Building` model using Django's `annotate`? I have a similar situation where I only have access to the top-level model